# How to bind database values in an ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, data-binding

I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web app using identity. The app has users and admin. The admin can create new tasks and assign them to the users.

I'm really stuck with the last one, trying and searching for a solution, but implementing them goes wrong.

My database has `AspNetUsers` which as you know, contains `user Id`, `Task` which has `taskId` and recently added `Assign` which has *both* user and task Id. So my idea about it is to create a dropdown which is populated with user names from the database. This option will be in every "Details" page, which means that the user will be assigned to the current task the admin is seeing.

From `TasksController`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(long? id)
{
        Assign model = new Assign();

        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var task = await _context.Task
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.TaskId == id);

        if (task == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(task);
}
```

Assign model:

```
public partial class Assign
{
    public long AssignId { get; set; }
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Task model:

```
public partial class Task
{
    [Key]
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Details.cshtml

```
@model TaskManager2.Models.Task


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Task</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Category)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DueDate)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DueDate)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Comments)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.TaskId">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a> |
    <a asp-action="Assign" asp-controller="Admin">Assign</a> 
</div>
```

Assign here takes you to another page, but it doesn't have to be like that. It is just something that I tried and didn't work.

The idea:

[image: here's the idea]

Please let me know if there's any other part of the program you need to see. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Include the View  in your question.

Comment: @JerdineSabio I added the view